# I want to know the tag approach defined in javascript innerHTML

Tags: javascript

```
var list = document.createElement("div");

list.innerHTML = '<ul>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>1</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>2</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>3</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>4</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>5</span>'+
        '</li>'+
    '</ul>';
```

After creating a div element with createElement

I filled the inner content through innerHTML.

I don't know how to access each li or ul here.

If anyone knows, thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want any action on each element then you need to create an element like div.

Or

```
var list = document.createElement("div");

list.innerHTML = '<ul>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>1</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>2</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>3</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>4</span>'+
        '</li>'+
        '<li>'+
            '<span>5</span>'+
        '</li>'+
    '</ul>';
var liElements = list.querySelectorAll('li')
console.log(liElements)
```

'liElements' contain all li elements in your div.

you can refer this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll